# how to create installer for the apps or copy them?

Tags: package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

i've installed a lot of apps by ubuntu software center(USC). i want to copy my apps to another pc. my internet connection is slow so i cant dl them from USC Again. is there any way to make an installer for them & install them on another ubuntu pc or to copy them to another pc?

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your installed softwares are located at `/var/cache/apt/archives`. If you haven't run `sudo apt-get clean` or `sudo apt-get autoclean`, you can copy them to an external drive and again copy them in another pc in the same location i.e `/var/cache/apt/archives` and install through software center. Unless the newer version than the installed one in your first pc is available from the repository, the software center will install from cache so you need not download the same software twice.